# How to add multiple ImageAnalysis.Analyzer

Tags: android, android-camera2, google-mlkit

I like to create a app which analyse image with face also with the text in the image at same time.

How can I use the two image analyser at same time and get the callback for both detection at same time using ML kit library and CameraX

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use multiple image analysers for multiple tasks. You can execute all your analysis in one.
First define a typealias for what you want to return:

```
typealias DetectionsResultListener = (detection: Detection) -> Unit
```

here `Detection` is a data class. So you can add results of multiple detections inside. Or create multiple type aliases like

```
typealias FaceDetectionsResultListener = (faceDetection: FaceDetection) -> Unit

typealias TextDetectionsResultListener = (textDetection: TextDetection) -> Unit
```

then it comes down to creating your ImageAnalysis class.

```
class FrameAnalyzer(val detectionsResultListener: DetectionsResultListener)
: ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
     override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
         ... some analysis done here...
         detectionsResultListener(detections) // callback with results here

     } 
}
```

Note that, If you used 2 type aliases, replace
`class FrameAnalyzer(val detectionsResultListener: DetectionsResultListener)`

with:

`class FrameAnalyzer(val faceDetectionsResultListener: FaceDetectionsResultListener, val textDetectionsResultListener: TextDetectionsResultListener)`

And when you are creating it:

```
ImageAnalysis.Builder()
        .setTargetResolution(targetResolution)
        .setTargetRotation(rotation)
        .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
        .build()
        .also {
            it.setAnalyzer(executor, FrameAnalyzer { detections ->

                val face = detections.face // Detection data class has face member
                val text = detections.text // Detection data class has text member
            })
        }
```